# My website wont load for me but loads on other computers and my tablet

Tags: dns

I have a problem. My website wont load on my pc, but it loads on other computers and my tablet.
I've flushed the dns in my computer, cleared browser cache and cookies, the site is not blocked in the hosts file.
The site sometimes works but sometimes doesnt, it works all the time on other computers and tablet though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is quite vague. Have you perhaps changed the DNS-sever you query? I've had some problems while using some shady openDNS alternative.

(network adapter properties, ip v4 properties, "use the following dns server addresses")

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean here.
I havent changed anything myself.

Comment: Here is what usually happens when you enter a site in a browser: The browser fires a DNS request, the OS queries it's caching (if found the ip comes from caches), after that the hosts file is addressed, if there is nothing there, you query your DNS server (usually your gateway). You can change your DNS server. Please verify this is still automatically. In Network Centrum > properties of your WiFi/lan adapter > properties of 'internet protocol version 4' > 'obtain DNS server addresses auto' vs 'Use the following DNS server addresses'. You need the first.

Comment: If that is auto, try pinging your site.. See if the problem only exists in the browser or wether it's system-wide:
In command prompt type 'ping www.mysite.com', see if you get a result/an IP

Comment: http://puu.sh/kATVW/97693e41ad.JPG. It is auto. When pinging I get the IP of my website.

Comment: If pinging works, the problem is most likely is in your browser. Have you tried reaching your site from other browsers? Chrome, firefox, opera, hell even IE might help. (believe me, browsers have a life of their own. They accumulate data. Never a good thing.) If another browser works, try clearing your history/cache/cookies/.. If not, report back ;)

Comment: I tried Chrome, FireFox, Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer. None of them work. I have cleared cache and cookies on all of them.

Comment: Me to have the same problem? i tried what you set all but still the problem exist